# JQuery TODO list, remove list removing everything

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to implement a small todo list with vanilla javascript, but whenever I try to remove something it just removes everything below it as well. But the same function works find for other operations like change and checkbox. Can someone explain what's happening and what can be the fix?

```js
$(function() {
  let counter = 0

  $('body').css('background-color', localStorage.getItem('theme'))
  if (localStorage.getItem('theme') == 'black') {
    $('.header').addClass('header-dark')
    $('#checkTheme').attr('Checked', 'checked')
  }

  $('#checkTheme').click(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'black')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'black')
      $('.header').addClass('header-dark')
      $('#checkTheme').attr('Checked', 'checked')
    } else {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'rgb(245, 239, 249)')
      localStorage.setItem('theme', 'rgb(245, 239, 249)')
      $('.header').removeClass('header-dark')
    }
  })

  let paginating = () => {
    $('.my-pagination-container').remove()
    $('.output').paginathing({
      perPage: 3,
      firstLast: false,
      activeClass: 'my-active',
      ulClass: 'my-pagination',
      containerClass: 'my-pagination-container'
    })
  }

  $(`.first-input`).keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      addingNewItems()
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('.addBtn').on('click', function() {
    addingNewItems()
  });

  let addingNewItems = () => {
    counter++

    if ($('#input').val() != '') {
      appendText()
    }
    $('#input').val('')

    function appendText() {

      var onePunct = `<div class='one-item' style='order: ${counter};'>
         <div class='display-changable' style='display:flex;align-items: center;justify-content:space-between;'>
         <div  class='form-check d-flex align-items-center'>
         <div>
         <input type="checkbox" class='form-check-input checkbox' id="flexCheckDefault${counter}">
         </div>
         <div>
         <label class='form-check-label text-to-do' for="flexCheckDefault${counter}">${$('#input').val()}</label>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class='d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center'>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success editBtn">Edit</button>
         <div class='trash ps-2'>
         <span class="iconify" data-icon="bi:trash-fill"" data-width="29"></span>
         </div>
         </div>
         </div>
         <br>
         <input type="text" placeholder='${$('#input').val()}' class="form-control editInput display-none" >
        <hr>
          </div>`;
      $(".output").append(onePunct);

      if (counter > 3)
        paginating()
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < $('.checkbox').length; i++) {
      $(`.checkbox:eq(${i})`).on('change', () => {
        $(`.text-to-do:eq(${i})`).wrap('<s/>')
        $(`.one-item:eq(${i})`).css('opacity', '0.5')
        $(`.checkbox:eq(${i})`).attr('disabled', '')
        $(`.editInput:eq(${i})`).removeClass('display-block')
      })

      $(`.trash:eq(${i})`).on('click', (event) => {
        counter++
        $(`.one-item:eq(${i})`).remove()
      })

      $(`.editBtn:eq(${i})`).on('click', () => {
        if (!$(`.checkbox:eq(${i})`).attr('disabled')) {
          if (!$(`.one-item:eq(${i})`).hasClass('classForCheck')) {
            $(`.editInput:eq(${i})`).addClass('display-block');
            $(`.one-item:eq(${i})`).addClass('classForCheck')
          }

          $(`.editInput:eq(${i})`).keypress(function(event) {
            var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
              $(`.text-to-do:eq(${i})`).text($(`.editInput:eq(${i})`).val())
              $(`.editInput:eq(${i})`).removeClass('display-block')
              $(`.one-item:eq(${i})`).removeClass('classForCheck')
            }
            event.stopPropagation();
          });
        }
      })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <!-- CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css" />

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <br>

  <div class="themes mb-4">

    <div>
      <span class="iconify" data-icon="fa-solid:sun" data-width="25" style="color: rgb(177, 154, 0);"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-switch success switch-flex">
      <input class="form-check-input form-check-input-1" type="checkbox" role="switch" id="checkTheme">
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="iconify" data-icon="ic:baseline-mode-night" data-width="25" style="color: rgb(174, 154, 23);"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">


    <div class="row">

      <div class="col col-md-8 offset-md-2 col-xl-6 offset-xl-3">
        <h2 class="header">To do list</h2>
        <div class="content card">
          <div class="to-do-list d-flex flex-column  align-items-center">

            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input id="input" type="text" class="form-control first-input" placeholder="Add New Task" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary addBtn btn-success p-1" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                        <span class="iconify" data-icon="ant-design:plus-circle-filled" style="color: white;" data-width="30"></span>
                     </button>
            </div>

            <div class="output">
              <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="" name="" id=""> -->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="pagination"></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>







  <script src="./jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./paginathing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.iconify.design/2/2.2.1/iconify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery-ui-1.13.2.custom/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./alertifyjs/alertify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-A3rJD856KowSb7dwlZdYEkO39Gagi7vIsF0jrRAoQmDKKtQBHUuLZ9AsSv4jD4Xa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./js/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Delete function is inside the for loop, whenever you add a new item it goes through the whole list and add event listener to each item.

Comment: You're using a lot of jQuery for something you're trying to write in plain JS...

Comment: Can you please include the relevant HTML and CSS in the question so we can see a full working example of the problem.

Comment: Please add the HTML/CSS to the snippet I added.

Comment: Updated question with html

Comment: `$('.my-pagination-container').remove()` <-- This causes all elements with that class to be removed and even if there is only one match, everything within it will be removed as well.

Comment: You should probably remove the for-loop entirely and access the index (if you need it) of the currently (clicked) element from within the event handler

Comment: Every time you use the Add button you add event listeners to every delete button, without removing the old ones. Clicking on the delete button will then call `.remove()` multiple times, each one removing different elements.

Comment: Instead of adding all these event listeners in a loop, you should use event delegation to bind listeners to all the elements with the same class. And then use DOM navigation methods to access the elements in the same container as the button.